# What is the difference between these these two snippets of c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

While working through a DX11 tutorial I came across this bit of code:

```
typedef struct
{
  float x, y, z;
}VertexType;
```

How is this different from:

```
struct VertexType
{
  float x, y, z;
};
```

I have read some other questions on typedef and it does not seem to be normally used as it is here. Can anyone explain if there is difference?

Comment: The first is a C-ism, the second is more idiomatic C++.

Comment: Ok thank you. I just found this answer too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c/612350#612350
It seems I had to search the term "typedef struct" not just "typedef"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one was born with C and is basically just legacy in C++, the second one is the C++ way of declaring a `struct`. There's no practical difference between the two, except that the latter would not compile in C.